# Blog / Message - How do I fix that empty message divs will piling on / next to each other and make the close button work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm making a sort of blog posting system or TODO list, however you want to call it.
I want that the following can happen / is possible:

- [Working] The user types something in the textarea
- [Working] The user clicks on the button.
- [Working] A new div will be created with the text of the textarea.
- [Working] The textarea will be empty.
- [Not Working] The user has got the choice to delete the post by clicking the 'X' on the right side of each '.post' div.

BUT: If I click on the button when there's nothing in the textarea, there appears an empty div, with only an 'X' close button, no background color either. They appear on the *same line* as the previous message, so you can get a lot of 'X's next to each other.
AND: Clicking the 'X' close button doesn't do anything. **No errors in Firefox console.**

If it's not clear enough, run this JSFiddle, click the button and I think you'll understand what I mean:
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HydraCles/yueqbrpv/)

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="blog">
        <h1>Blog post application</h1>
        <div id="post-system">  
            <textarea id="poster" rows="5" cols="50" placeholder="Update status."></textarea>
            <div id="button">Post</div>
            <div id="posts">
            </div>
        </div>                  
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

jQuery Script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#button').click(function () {
        var text = $('#poster').val();
        $('#posts').prepend("<div class='post'>" + text + "<span class='close-post'>&times;</span></div>");
        $('#poster').val('');
    });

    $('.close-post').click(function () {
        ('.close-post').parent().hide();
    });
});
</script>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

#blog {
    background-color: blue;
    margin: 50px;
    padding: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: white;
    display: block;
}

#poster {
    color: default;
    resize: none;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-decoration: blink;
    font-size: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}

#button {
    background-color: #00FFFF;
    color: white;
    border: 2px solid white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 50px;
    float: left;
}

.post {
    background-color: white;
    color: blue;
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: auto;
    display: block;
}

.close-post {
    margin-right: 10px;
    float: right;
    color: red;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to have two issues:

**1) You don't want a post to be created if the `textarea` is empty**

Simple fix . . . check to see if it is empty, before calling the logic to add the new post (and use jQuery's `$.trim()` to account for only blank spaces):

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    var text = $.trim($('#poster').val());

    if (text !== "") {
        $('#posts').prepend("<div class='post'>" + text + "<span class='close-post'>&times;</span></div>");
        $('#poster').val('');
    }
});
```

**2) The 'X' buttons are not closing the posts**

This also should be a pretty easy fix . . . the reason that they are not working is because the 'X' buttons don't exist when the page is loaded so `$('.close-post').click(function() {` is not binding to them on page load.  You will need to delegate that event binding, so that it will apply to the 'X' buttons that are dynamically added  **after** the page is loaded.

Now, not knowing what version of jQuery that you are using (I can't access jsFiddle from work), I'll point you to the right place to figure out the correct way to do it:  https://api.jquery.com/on/

If it is jQuery 1.7 or higher, you would do it like this:

```
$("#posts").on("click", ".close-post", function() {
    $(this).parent().hide();
});
```

If your version is earlier than that, then investigate the jQuery `.delegate()` and `.live()` methods to determine which is the right one to use for your code..

Comment: Hi, I've just made up an idea that I can maybe add a button which allows / de-allows to send empty messages. We now have that nothing happens when there's an empty message. Do you have an idea for an empty div like all the others which _does_ appear?

Comment: You should be able to handle that with CSS (specifically, make sure that the `divs` have a width and height, even if they are empty . . . that can affect whether or not other style definitions are visible), but, since I can't access jsFiddle right now, it's harder for me to look at what would need to be done.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#button').click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var text= $('#poster').val();
            if (text === '') {
                alert('Nothing to post!');
                return;
            }

            $('#posts').prepend("<div class='post'>" + text + "<span class='close-post'>&times;</span></div>");
            $('#poster').val('');
        });

        $('#posts').on('click', '.close-post', function() {
            $(this).closest('.post').fadeOut();
        });
    });
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dekkard/uh60bf5r/2/)

Answer (score 1):

The way you are doing this, the user will only ever see what they are posting - if you're trying for a chat type where users talk to each other then you will need to store what is being typed on the server side and refresh the screen using something like ajax

but in response to your question, you need to bind the close click like this:

```
$( "#posts" ).on( "click", ".close-post", function() {
    $(this).parent().hide(); // $(this) is the clicked icon, the way you did it above wouldn't as if it had the dollar, it would close all .close-post parents
});
```

See the part about delegated events: http://api.jquery.com/on/